# Decorate a Rails engine's helper to include a concern from the main app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to include an ActiveSupport::Concern from an app in an engine, by decorating one of the engine's helper modules.
Here is the Helper from the engine:

```
module MyEngine
  module MyHelper
  end
end
```

Here is the Concern from the main app :

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def do_this
  end

  def do_that
  end
end
```

Below is the decorated engine helper that needs to include the concern (for use in the engine views) - it is declared in the **main app**, using the decorator pattern described in the [Rails guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers) :

```
module MyEngine
  module MyHelper
    include MyConcern

    def do_stuff
    end
  end
end
```

The decorated helper is properly loaded by the engine, but the engine views are only able to call "do_stuff". The methods from MyConcern are  unavailable, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why.
I also tried to include the concern by embedding it in a MyEngine::MyHelper.module_eval call, but that didn't work either.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue before ? Am I taking this the wrong way ?

Comment: is my answer good with your requirements ? if not, please complete your question

Comment: "Am I taking this the wrong way?" - yes most likely. The idea is that an engine should encapsulate a reusable piece of functionality. While an engine may rely on the parent app for the actual implementation (like Devise for example) it should not generally have a  hard dependency on the parent application as that would make it really hard to test the engine in isolation or reuse it. This makes the whole process of extracting the functionality pointless.

Comment: @max thanks for the feedback, I do agree that an engine should not have dependencies on the host app. This is why I chose to decorate the helper on the main app side, which is not a "hard dependency" I believe, more of a dependency injection provided by the main app to customize the engine's helper. The purpose here is to use the Concern methods do_this and do_that in the engine's view, as it shares a common partial with the main app (typically a top nav pane with links).

Comment: So then basically what you really want to do is declare a module in your main app that extends the module from the engine and not vice versa. Note that you want to use extend and not include when you are adding methods to a module.

Comment: @max I edited the question to clarify as I realize that my use of the decorator pattern was unclear. I did declare the decorated helper on the main app side, and methods declared directly there are available in the engine. What doesn't work for me is when I try to include an ActiveSupport::Concern module (also from the main app) in that decorated helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a way to do this in a "clean" way, as mentioned in the following comment : https://groups.google.com/g/rubyonrails-core/c/PaABJDXnxyo/m/k-QUJEi9a9wJ

The idea is to add an empty placeholder helper in the engine, for example :

```
module MyEngine
  module ExtendableHelper
  end
end
```

And then override it in the main app, by adding methods or including concerns, other gems' helpers, etc...

```
module MyEngine
  module ExtendableHelper
    extend OtherGemFromMainApp::UsefulHelper
    include MainAppConcern
    
    def other_useful_method
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Thus the helper used by the engine is the one provided by the app, and the *UsefulHelper* methods can be called in the engine views.

Answer (score 0):

I renplaced MyHelper from module to class

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def do_this
    "do this"
  end

  def do_that
    "do that"
  end
end

module MyEngine
  class MyHelper
    include ::MyConcern

    def do_stuff
      "do stuff"
    end
  end
end
```

When calling :

```
MyEngine::MyHelper.new.do_stuff
MyEngine::MyHelper.new.do_this
MyEngine::MyHelper.new.do_that
```

The result will be :

> do stuff
>
> do this
>
> do that

Comment: Hi @Xero, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately using a class is not an option here, since Rails requires helpers to be declared as modules in order to include them in the views context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be reasoning about this backwards.

If your engine provides:

```
module MyEngine
  module MyHelper
    def foo
    end
  end
end
```

You can extend the method (you could call it decorate but i'm not sure if this is technically the decorator pattern) in your main app:

```
module MainApp
  module MyHelper
    extend ::MyEngine::MyHelper
    def foo
      super
      do_something_else
    end
  end
end
```

When using the module-mixin pattern (which is what ActiveSupport::Concern does) you extend modules with modules and include modules in classes.

If you engine and main app "share a partial" - it should just be placed in the engine as Rails will first look for the view when rendering in the app/views directory of the application before looking for it the mounted engines.

The main app can thus always override the functionality provided by the engine while the inverse is not true.

If you want to make a method provided by an engine configurable a better idea is to use a Rails configuration setting (or a seperate module configuration) or just method arguments rather than some crazy circular dependency circus.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It is getting clearer, however it is not quite the same use case : my ActiveSupport::Concern module provides methods to generate navigation links. Those links are rendered in the "top nav partial", both in the main app and in the engine views (the views know which partial to use with a config setting, as suggested). When I extend the engine helper and explicitly add methods to it, it does work. However, if I try to include another module (the nav links already declared in a concern), the methods are unavailable to the engine.